# how to delete a file from folder in php

Tags: php, file, delete-file

I have a folder `'items'` in which there are 3 files `item1.txt, item2.txt and item3.txt.`
I want to `delete item2.txt` file from folder. I am using the below code but it not deleting a file from folder. Can any body help me in that.

```
<?php
        $data="item2.txt";
        $dir = "items";
        $dirHandle = opendir($dir);
        while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) {
            if($file==$data) {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }

        closedir($dirHandle);

?>
```

Comment: unlink( $dir."/".$data);

Comment: Check is correct path of file in mentioned

Comment: @Tahir Yasin Once i get answer I will accept

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Initially the folder should have 777 permissions

```php
$data = "item2.txt";
$dir = "items";
while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) {
    if ($file==$data) {
        unlink($dir.'/'.$file);
    }
}
```

or try

```php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'items/item2.txt';
unlink($path);
```

Answer (score 5):

No need of while loop here for just deleting a file, you have to pass path of that file to unlink() function, as shown below.

```
$file_to_delete = 'items/item2.txt';
unlink($file_to_delete);
```

Please read details of unlink() function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Answer (score 3):

There is one bug in your code, you haven't given the correct path

```
<?php
        $data="item2.txt";    
        $dir = "items";    
        $dirHandle = opendir($dir);    
        while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) {    
            if($file==$data) {
                unlink($dir."/".$file);//give correct path,
            }
        }    
        closedir($dirHandle);

?>
```

- [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Comment: @xing are you sure your path is correct, because your php page directory should have "items" folder

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple:

```
$file='a.txt';

    if(unlink($file))
    {
        echo "file named $file has been deleted successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "file is not deleted";
    }

//if file is in other folder then do as follows

unlink("foldername/".$file);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($file==$data) {
  unlink( $dir .'/'. $file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try renaming it to the trash or a temp folder that the server have access ****UNLESS IT'S sensitive data.

```
rename($old, $new) or die("Unable to rename $old to $new.");
```

Comment: $variables are self explainatory